# WordPress adding hyphen in custom post url

Tags: wordpress, url, hyphenation

I have created a custom post type in my WordPress application and I want its URL to be separated via Hyphens. For example, The name of the custom post is `Singh Across The World` and in URL `singhacrosstheworld` and want it to be `singh-across-the-world`.

I tried using `singh-across-the-world` / `singh_across_the_world` instead of `singhAcrossTheWorld` as the first parameter, but it did not work.

**Here is the code, please have a look:**

```
register_post_type("singhAcrossTheWorld", [
    "capability_type"   => "post",
    "description"       => "Holds our Singh's specific data",
    "public"            => true,
    "menu_position"     => 6,
    "has_archive"       => true,
    "show_admin_column" => true,
    "supports"          => [
        "title",
        "editor",
        "thumbnail",
        "excerpt",
        "revisions",
        "comments",
        "custom-fields",
        "page-attributes"
    ],
    "taxonomies"        => [
        "post_tag"
    ],
    "labels" => [
        "name"               => "Singh across the world",
        "singular_name"      => "Singh across the world",
        "add_new"            => "Add Singh",
        "add_new_item"       => "Add Singh",
        "edit_item"          => "Edit Singh",
        "new_item"           => "New Singh",
        "all_items"          => "All Singhs",
        "view_item"          => "View Singh",
        "search_items"       => "Search Singhs",
        "not_found"          => "No Singhs found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Singhs found in the Trash",
        "parent_item_colon"  => "",
        "menu_name"          => "S. A. T. W."
    ]
]);
```

Comment: here-ya-go-m8 : `'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'singh-across-the-world' ),` - throw that into your `register_post_type()`

Comment: remember to flush your permalinks afterwards

Comment: You might be better semantically just using a taxonomy term or category for this. For example, change the post type to name and have the taxonomy term 'singh' under category. Just a thought!

Comment: Originally I developed it using the category, but the client wants a separate section in the left menu therefore I have to change it to custom post.

Comment: Thanks @Stender, It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this args `rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'singh-across-the-world'
        )`

```
register_post_type("singhAcrossTheWorld", [
    "capability_type"   => "post",
    "description"       => "Holds our Singh's specific data",
    "public"            => true,
    "menu_position"     => 6,
    "has_archive"       => true,
    "show_admin_column" => true,
    "supports"          => [
        "title",
        "editor",
        "thumbnail",
        "excerpt",
        "revisions",
        "comments",
        "custom-fields",
        "page-attributes"
    ],
    "taxonomies"        => [
        "post_tag"
    ],
    "labels" => [
        "name"               => "Singh across the world",
        "singular_name"      => "Singh across the world",
        "add_new"            => "Add Singh",
        "add_new_item"       => "Add Singh",
        "edit_item"          => "Edit Singh",
        "new_item"           => "New Singh",
        "all_items"          => "All Singhs",
        "view_item"          => "View Singh",
        "search_items"       => "Search Singhs",
        "not_found"          => "No Singhs found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Singhs found in the Trash",
        "parent_item_colon"  => "",
        "menu_name"          => "S. A. T. W."
    ],
    'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'singh-across-the-world'
    )
]);
```